# Configuring Serverless to handle required path parameters

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'm new to serverless and writing my first service. It is built for the AWS API gateway and node.js lambda functions. Consider this as my `serverless.yaml` file:

```yaml
service: applicationCatalog
frameworkVersion: '2'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
functions:
  listShirts:
    handler: handler.listShirts
    events:
    - httpApi: GET /
  createShirt:
    handler: handler.createShirt
    events:
    - httpApi: POST /
  getShirt:
    handler: handler.getShirt
    events:
    - httpApi:
        method: GET
        path: "/{shirtId}"
        request:
          parameters:
            paths:
              shirtId: true
  deleteShirt:
    handler: handler.deleteShirt
    events:
    - httpApi:
        method: DELETE
        path: "/{shirtId}"
        request:
          parameters:
            paths:
              shirtId: true
resources: {}
```

The functions listShirts, createShirt, and getShirt all work as I expected, and deleteShirt works too when a ShirtId is passed. The issue is when I don't pass the ShirtId on a delete. Assuming my service url is "https://shirts.mywardrobeapi.com". I'd expect this request:

```
DELETE https://shirts.mywardrobeapi.com
```

to trigger an error response from the API gateway. Instead, the deleteShirt function is invoked. Of course I could handle this simple check inside the function, but I thought that's what the `{ "shirtId" : true }` setting in the `serverless.yaml` file was for. How can I get this setting to treat `shirtId` as required and not invoke the function when it's not provided? If I can't, what is this purpose of this setting?

Comment: I strongly recommend for you to use YAML instead of JSON, it's more readable and it's possible to add comments. You should first investigate the generated the CloudFormation that was generated, search for `DELETE`, and make sure the values are as expected. Feel free to reply with your outputs, we can investigate them together. Here's a good reference - [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#lambda-proxy-integration)

Comment: Converted to yaml and updated the post. Same result. Also, I checked the CloudFormation file and I didn't see anything odd, however, this is new to me and I very well could have missed something.

Comment: Could you check that the received request is truly `DELETE` in the API Gateway logs?

Comment: Yes, it is in the logs

Comment: @ARM- it seems that somewhere in your configuration, there's ANY on "/", or something similar. You should get the expected error when omitting `shirtId` for `DELETE`. Any chance you can share your CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [Middy](https://github.com/middyjs/middy) and [validator middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@middy/validator) for handling required parameters.
Yep, the disadvantage is that your lambda is triggered all the time. But also you obtain

- the flexibility of keeping handling required params in the code
- clear logging if the parameters were wrong
- you may also validate *outgoing responses*
- keeps you *serverless.yaml* cleaner

We prefer the middy more than precise configure of Gateway API.

Comment: This makes sense. I was up in the air about doing it this way to begin with. I think you've tipped my decision. Thanks! However, it doesn't address the question why the property { "shirtId" : true } doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Whether shirtId is true, false, or if I just remove the entire request: parameters: querystrings: block, it all behaves the same. Was wondering if I was doing wrong.

Comment: @elbik, thanks for the Middy shout out. FYI v2 is in alpha right now :)

Comment: @willFarrell - thank you, appreciate your effort. Definitely, I will check it :)